# In this code, there's an initialization problem that's causing our function to behave incorrectly. Can you find the problem and fix it?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, count

```
def count_down(start_number):
  while (current > 0):
    print(current)
    current -= 1
  print("Zero!")

count_down(3)
```

Comment: This is an *extremely* basic bug. You need to be able to fix you own bugs like this, without asking strangers on the internet to debug it for you. There is no other way to learn.

Comment: Some unsolicited advice: you might be able to get through your first few CS assignments at BUBT this way, but you're going to crash into a brick wall during final exams.  It'd be easier to drop the class now and find something you're more interested in studying.  :)

Comment: @Samwise That isn't helpful.

Comment: Drop rate for freshman classes when I was studying CS was over 50%; maybe it's not that high at every school, but if you're giving up and asking other people to do your homework for you this early, you're definitely going to be one of the people who drops.  Dropping a class closer to the end of the semester can seriously derail your chances to switch to a better major.  Not everyone needs to learn to code; better to cut losses early if you gave it a shot and have already decided it's not worth doing.

Comment: @Samwise I don't disagree that if they keep approaching their homework this way they won't get very far, but it is a little premature to suggest that they find something else to study.

Comment: please be kind and helpful, asking and learning isn't that bad right ??

Comment: it might be a simple problem thats how people learn isn't it ??

Comment: That is how people learn, but that is not the charter of Stack Overflow.  Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Homework Question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: thank you so much for your kind information I won't repeat this problem thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of current use start_number

```
 def count_down(start_number):
      while (start_number > 0):
        print(start_number)
        start_number -= 1
      print("Zero!")
    
    count_down(3)

output:
        3
        2
        1
        Zero!
```

Comment: thank you so much its solved <3

Answer (score 0):

Running the code reveals exactly where the problem is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in count_down
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current' referenced before assignment
```